# Get index of array object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

This is the code I'm trying to finish

```
-(IBAction)theButtonIsSelected:(id)sender {

    NSMutableDictionary *mutDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[detailsDataSource objectAtIndex:detailIndex]];
    [mutDict setObject:@"Yes" forKey:@"Favorite"];

    NSString *nameString = [mutDict valueForKey:@"Name"];

    NSArray *allObjects;
    allObjects = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    NSMutableArray *tmpMutArr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:allObjects];
    int index;
     //I think I just need a little piece right here to set the current allObjectsIndex to match nameString?
    [tmpMutArr replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:mutDict]];

    allObjects = nil;
    allObjects = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:tmpMutArr];

    [allObjects writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    }
```

This is my question:

```
if (what I'm trying to do above can be done) {
How to finish it?
} else {
How to make a function to change the "Favorite" key's value of plist object, 
when detailsDataSource not always containing the complete list of objects?
That's why I'm trying to include allObjects and index in this code.
}
```

EDIT:

Code now look like this:

```
     NSMutableDictionary *mutDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[detailsDataSource objectAtIndex:detailIndex]];
     [mutDict setObject:@"Yes" forKey:@"Favorite"];

     NSString *nameString = [[detailsDataSource objectAtIndex:detailIndex] valueForKey:@"Name"];

     NSArray *allObjectsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

     NSMutableArray *tmpMutArr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:allObjectsArray];


     if(int i=0;i<[tmpMutArr count];i++)
//Errors ^here              and here^
     {
     if([[tmpMutArr  objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
     {
     NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [tmpMutArr  objectAtIndex:i];
     if([tempDict valueForKey:@"Name" == [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%", nameString];) //Is this correct?
     {
     index = i; //index of dictionary
     }
     }
     }

     [tmpMutArr replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:mutDict]];

     allObjectsArray = nil;
     allObjectsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:tmpMutArr];

     [allObjectsArray writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Errors: 1 Expected expression 2 undeclared identifier 'i' how to declare I and fix the other error?

Comment: You might want to look into using `NSNumber` for the favourite object, by using `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]` rather then the string "Yes"

Comment: Yeah but I'll fix that later, now I'm concentrating on getting a correct plist copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get index of dictionary like this:

```
 if(int i=0;i<[tmpMutArr count];i++)
 {
   if([[tmpMutArr  objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
   {
      NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [tmpMutArr  objectAtIndex:i];
      if([tempDict objectForKey:@"Favorite")
      {
         index = i; // here u have your index of dictionary
      }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Looks like its gonna do it but can you show me how to fix the errors in question edit?